# How to prove that this stochastic matrix has a limiting distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have the following stochastic matrix with $p_{ij} > 0$ and $\sum_j p_{ij} = 1$

$$ 
P = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
p_{11} & p_{12} & 0      & 0      & 0      & 0      \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23} & 0      & 0      & 0      \\
0      & p_{32} & p_{33} & p_{34} & 0      & 0      \\
0      & 0      & p_{43} & p_{44} & p_{45} & 0      \\
0      & 0      & 0      & p_{54} & p_{55} & p_{56} \\
0      & 0      & 0      & 0      & p_{65} & p_{66}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now this stochastic matrix has a limiting distribution because it is irreducible, it is possible to get to any state from any state, and it is aperiodic, $(P^1)_{ii} > 0$.

Now I have the following stochastic distribution.

$$ 
P = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
p_{11} & p_{12} & 0      & 0      & 0      & 0      \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23} & 0      & 0      & 0      \\
0      & p_{32} & p_{33} & p_{34} & 0      & 0      \\
0      & 0      & p_{43} & p_{44} & p_{45} & 0      \\
0      & 0      & 0      & p_{54} & p_{55} & p_{56} \\
1      & 0      & 0      & 0      & 0      & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

While $P$ is irreducible it is not aperiodic, its period is not $1$ but $6$ because $(P^6)_{ii} > 0$.

I want to prove that the stochastic matrix also has a limiting distribution. How do I do this?

Comment: The second matrix P **is** aperiodic.

Comment: Why is the second matrix aperiodic? As I did understand a stochastic matrix is aperiodic iff $(P^1)_{ii} > 0$, which is not the case in the second matrix?

Comment: No this is not a necessary condition, but if $(P^1)_{ii}\gt0$ for at least one state $i$ then $P$ is aperiodic. And in your case, it seems that $(P^1)_{11}\gt0$.

Comment: @Did, oh okay I see, clearly I did misunderstood the exact definition of periodicity. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Did, small question, is the second $P$ matrix also ergodic? No right? Because not all states are aperiodic?

Comment: Of course it is. "Not all states are aperiodic" is not a meaningful assertion.

Comment: @Did, okay thanks, the reason I was confused because, wikipedia says, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Ergodicity, "A state i is said to be ergodic if it is aperiodic and positive recurrent. In other words, a state i is ergodic if it is recurrent, has a period of 1 and it has finite mean recurrence time. If all states in an irreducible Markov chain are ergodic, then the chain is said to be ergodic."